# what should I do to create a web application using grails 3 and angular?

Tags: angular, grails, grails3

https://www.djamware.com/post/5a10b5f580aca75eadc12d6c/grails-3-angular-5-profile-crud-web-application-example this tutorial create 2 project (server and client) but after i looking another tutorial, like http://hantsy.blogspot.com/2013/11/create-restful-application-with_7975.html it's only create 1 project, i tried to create using 2 profile like

```
grails create-app grails-angular --profile angular --profile=rest-api
```

but now i don't understand what should i do.. is it true or no?

how to use angular in grails3? someone told me to use plugin, another article told me to create using profile.

please I'm really confused here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with the profile would be the easiest way to go, which will set you up with the right set of plug-ins. There are actually two angular plug-ins one that used angular 2, which I think has gotten updated over time with new versions, and a legacy profile that uses angular 1. You can read about the name change of the profiles here:
http://grailsblog.objectcomputing.com/posts/2017/04/12/angular-profiles.html

Going with the angular profile it doesn't give you a multi build project with, an angular client, and a grails back end. However it is possible to combine them, into one project/ deployable war:
http://guides.grails.org/angular2-combined/guide/index.html

I'm not much of a front end developer, but Grails does have guides:
http://guides.grails.org/grails-quickcasts-angularjs-scaffolding-with-grails-3/guide/index.html

http://grails.org/profiles.html

Hopefully that will help get you started. Beyond that if you are getting into angular, you might want to to look up separate tutorials on it.